# If I install Windows7 RC, will I need to repave later?

Tags: windows-7

I'm thinking of installing Windows7 RC. I'm wondering if the auto-updates along with a production licencense will be sufficient to convert the RC to the RTM. Or will I have to reinstall?

Comment: And will the 1-yr license work in such a case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Windows 7 RC will expire [June 2010](http://blogs.technet.com/springboard/default.aspx).  So you will be able to continue to use it until then.  You may be able to upgrade it to the full version, but most likely they will recommend a fresh install.

They recommended a reinstall when moving from the Beta to the RC, but they [provided a work around](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2009/04/07/delivering-a-quality-upgrade-experience.aspx).  Most likely they will provide a work around at RTM, if not you can probably find a way.

Additionally, nothing beats that fresh installed OS feeling.  Reinstalling after 12 months of use is probably a good plan anyway.

Comment: Add to that the frequent recommendations by Paul Thurott on Windows weekly to the effect of "you may be able to upgrade, but you're going to want to do a clean install"

Comment: If you reinstall the RTM copy, do you get 12 months? Or is the 12 month trial only for the RC?

Comment: It isn't a flexible 12 months from date of install.  There is a hard deactivation date of June 2010 for the RC.  I imagine the RTM will have different license behavior.

Comment: I've used the workaround to upgrade my development workstation from the beta to the RC. I will nuke-and-pave when the RTM comes out, but I wasn't prepared to do it on my workhorse machine when RTM is probably only 3 to 4 months away. I will say that I am starting to see some cracks and it will definitely be worth doing that clean install when the time comes.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [release blog](http://blogs.technet.com/springboard/archive/2009/04/30/windows-7-rc-is-available-for-technet-and-msdn-subscribers-to-download.aspx), you will need to reinstall.

Specifically:

> In both cases, you’ll need to rebuild your test PC to replace the operating system and reinstall all your programs and data.

Answer (score 2):

there's nothing better than a clean and fresh windows install

Comment: ... and then spending 2 days re-installing and re-configuring all of your apps, and another two weeks in frustration that all the minor helpers and settings you're so used to are not there.

Comment: ...but then you come out the other end fresh and reinvigorated, with expanded knowledge of where your data is and what your dependencies are.