# Upgrade from Windows 7 RC1 to Official Release

Tags: windows-7

Windows 7 RC is now available. What is the expiration and upgrade path for it?

- Upgrade to official Windows release -- will it be painless, or would it require a reformat / reinstall of all apps.
- Time limit -- will Win 7 RC stop working entirely and refuse to boot on June 1, 2010, or will it retain some limited functionality (e.g. allowing users to copy their data).

Should I install Win 7 RC to some friends who are eager to try it on their laptop, but are not incredibly computer-savvy (and would certainly not appreciate a complete toast-and-reinstall)?

**Edit:**
Sorry if this is a [duplicate](https://serverfault.com/questions/1855/if-i-install-windows7-rc-will-i-need-to-repave-later), but I'm primarily interested on your opinion on whether to recommend it to a non-technical user.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Upgrading windows 7 from Beta to RC and RC to RTM is not supported and if you try it you will get an error. It is possible to do, the instructions are [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2009/04/07/delivering-a-quality-upgrade-experience.aspx), but its not a great idea.

Upgrading is something I rarely do if I can help it, even with release software, it has som many opportunitys for errors and compatability problems, and doing so from pre-release software just increases the possibility of these.

Answer (score 3):

The expiration date is June 2010 but be aware that on March 2010 you'll start getting by-hourly shutdowns.

I'm sure that Windows 7 RC is stable enough to use it in your primary computer, but I wouldn't do it. I installed it on my laptop, but my main computer still has VISTA.

I wouldn't install Windows 7 to my friends either if that implies that I'll have to take care of their upgrades to the RTM version, which will probably require a fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft did announce that people running the RC1 candidate will receive a notice a month prior to the beginning of the bi-hourly shutdowns allowing the user to purchase or enter a legitimate key. I'm going to look for my source and if I'm able to find it I'll add it as a comment in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Since Vista the fresh install instead of upgrade is even more of a best practice method than before since it's rather easy. You export your data with the built-in migration tool and then reinstall, rounding it all off with reimporting all your data and settings...